# How to use sum(case) with three conditions

Tags: sql

I usually use sum(case) to get sum of some columns:

```
i.e. SUM(CASE WHEN over05 = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OK_05
```

and this is perfect when I have a column with two values, but when I have a column where I have three values:

```
 i.e. over 05 = '1' or 'X' or '2'
```

how can I do a sum(case)?

Comment: sum(case when (over05= '1' or over05='x' or over05='2') then 1 ELSE 0 end) ?

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP and not whatever db you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all three values to return the same thing, you should use `IN()`:

```
SUM(
    CASE
    WHEN over05 IN ('1', 'X', '2') THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END
) AS OK_05
```

If you want each value to return something different, you should use multiple `WHEN ... THEN` :

```
SUM(
    CASE
    WHEN over05 = '1' THEN 1
    WHEN over05 = 'X' THEN 2
    WHEN over05 = '2' THEN 3
    ELSE 0 END
) AS OK_05
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which one were you trying to achieve ?